# Best Programs for Team Workflow on Responsive Web Development

Tags: php, html, css, workflow

This is a question less about programming itself, and more about programming workflow. I've been a developer for a while now, and I'm now joining ranks with a designer. He designs in Photoshop, and I make his designs into a reality using my code editor.

I was wondering what programs you use to allow for the following:

- Website Design
- Turning Websites into HTML and CSS
- Adding Server-Side Language like PHP

Programs that have interested me a lot is Adobe's Edge utilities. However, I'm not really sure how they interact with with server-side actions, such as logging in and out, and there seems to be little documentation on it. What applications do you use for good workflow?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text 2 is my favourite.

Link: http://www.sublimetext.com/2